# How to populate dataTable with strongly typed Razor View Page

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, razor, datatables

I have a `dataTable` in strongly typed Razor View Page.Now as per my requirement I need to populate this with my Model of the page but i am not getting how to do it.Here is my dataTable Code..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var dt;
        var dataSet = [];
        dt = $("#Setup").dataTable({
            "data": dataSet,
            "paging": false,
            "responsive": true,
            "stateSave": true,
            "columns": [
                { "title": "<input type='checkbox' id='selectAll'>", "bSortable": false, "width": "5px", },
                { "title": "", "bSortable": false, "width": "5px" },
                { "title": "Code", "width": "50px" },
                { "title": "Name" }

            ]
        });

    });
```

My page is Razor View Page .Please help me to get it done..Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you should be able to inline your data from razor like this:

```
@{
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   foreach(row in model.MyTable)
   {
     sb.AppendFormat("['{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}'],",
        row.Field1, row.Field2, row.Field3, row.Field4);
   }
}
$(document).ready(function () {
        var dt;
        var dataSet = [@Html.Raw(sb.ToString(0, sb.Length - 1))];
        dt = $("#Setup").dataTable({
            "data": dataSet,
            "paging": false,
            "responsive": true,
            "stateSave": true,
            "columns": [
                { "title": "<input type='checkbox' id='selectAll'>", "bSortable": false, "width": "5px", },
                { "title": "", "bSortable": false, "width": "5px" },
                { "title": "Code", "width": "50px" },
                { "title": "Name" }

            ]
        });

    });
```

You should use `sb.Length - 1` in order to remove the last comma (`,`) from the output array. Using `Html.Raw()` prevents Razor from encoding the string which would ruin the JavaScript syntax.

Comment: .Thank you so much for your Answer.I am trying Once done i will Mark it as answer , incase i will get any issue, i will comment here .Thanks

Comment: @Amit..I updated my post with the code what i am trying with no luck.With the above code i am getting blank page and no error on console of firebug also.Please see the code and point out the mistake..Thanks

Comment: @Lara - I've updated my answer with a cleaner version already (sorry for the earlier, confusing version). Please try again like this.

Comment: @Amit..But was Okay as per my requirement ..Now i am getting `An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in 4tb2l5g3 but was not handled in user code` error on Razor View page..I am getting model as NULL Why is this happening..

Comment: @Lara - first version (and the way you used it in your edit) is *wrong*. sorry. please try again using current version. I don't think it will solve your exception though, that seems unrelated.

Comment: @Amit..Now i am able to return the Values but getting this error `SyntaxError: missing ] after element list `..Any fix for this ..

Comment: Is there a more efficient way to achieve this? Can it be done on the `Controller` side?

Answer (score 0):

It's easier: "data": @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.MyList)) - For me it works.